# SQL - UPDATE com valor a partir de SELECT

Tags: sql, select, sql-update

Caros, tenho duas tabelas (A e B), em que B tem uma chave estrangeira de A. Exemplo:

```
A(id, campo1, campo2)
B(id, idA, campo3, campo4)
```

Preciso contar a quantidade de `B.idA` e com isso definir um valor `true` ou `false` para atualizar o `campo2` de A. Pensei em duas formas (mas nenhuma delas funcionou):

```
UPDATE A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.idA SET A.campo2 = IIF(Count(B.idA) = 1, FALSE, TRUE);
```

e

```
UPDATE A SET A.campo2 = (SELECT IIF(Count(*) = 1, FALSE, TRUE) AS Nome FROM B WHERE B.idA >= 1 GROUP BY B.idA);
```

Não sei se todo SGBD tem essa cláusula `IIF`, estou usando o MSAccess. Ela é como um condicional ternário.
Qual é a forma correta de se fazer esse `UPDATE`?

Comment: A primeira forma, não sei nem dizer se existe, a segunda seria o mais próximo do possível, caso queira algo semelhante a um IIF na query, procure utilizar do case when.

Comment: Realmente, a primeira forma não funciona... Eu consegui resolver, simplificando a query. Vou postar a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver simplificando um pouco e mudando a lógica:

```
UPDATE A SET campo2 = True WHERE ((A.id) In (SELECT B.idA FROM B GROUP BY B.idA HAVING COUNT(*) > 1));
```

Eu precisava contar os `B.idA` para saber quais `B.idA` são repetidos e com isso setar um campo `boolean` para `true` em `A`. E fiz isso colocando uma restrição `WHERE` no `UPDATE`, e a restrição são os `B.id` repetidos. Com isso não foi preciso mais usar o `IIF`. Como são vários `B.idA` e eu vou atualizar toda a tabela `A` de uma vez, foi preciso usar o operador `In`, agrupar os `B.idA` e colocar o `COUNT(*)` na cláusula `HAVING`. Deu certo.